# Menu and Sumenu in odoo15

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-15

I am trying to add a submenu in a menu in odoo-15 website in xml part, so for that in xml i have written:

```
<record id="menu_solutions" model="website.menu">
    <field name="name">Solutions</field>
    <field name="parent_id" ref="website.main_menu"/>
    <field name="sequence" type="int">20</field>
</record>
<record id="menu_submenu_erp" model="website.menu">
    <field name="name">ERP</field>
    <field name="url">/shop</field>
    <field name="parent_id" ref="website_main_menu.menu_solutions"/>
    <field name="sequence" type="int">20</field>
</record>
```

i have researched in google for adding sub-menu and i have got some results and i have tried the same still i am getting 2 menus instead of a menu and a sub-menu of that menu

please let me know if still my question is unclear, any help will be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check the [create](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/addons/website/models/website_menu.py#L66-L97) function of the website menu, it is overriden to set the parent menu to the website top menu (`Top Menu for Website 1`) if the `website_id` field value is not provided.

Try to add the `website_id` field value to the menus.

***Example:***

```
<record id="menu_solutions" model="website.menu">
    <field name="name">Solutions</field>
    <field name="parent_id" search="[('parent_id', '=', False), ('website_id', '=', obj().env.ref('website.default_website').id)]"/>
    <field name="website_id" ref="website.default_website"/>
    <field name="sequence" type="int">20</field>
</record>

<record id="menu_submenu_erp" model="website.menu">
    <field name="name">ERP</field>
    <field name="url">/shop</field>
    <field name="website_id" ref="website.default_website"/>
    <field name="parent_id" ref="menu_solutions"/>
    <field name="sequence" type="int">20</field>
</record>
```

Comment: yes i do have tried by removing the `parent_id` field from the `Solutions`, and when i do that what happens is... i can see solutions in the menu but the `ERP` is neither in the Menu nor in the `Solutions` Sub menu.

Comment: Did you try the same example above?

Comment: yeah, if there is a possibility to share a image i will share that also

Comment: I tried it and the `ERP` menu is shown under `Solutions`

Comment: The important point is to know what does Odoo when you don't provide the `website_id` field value

Comment: here is what i did in code..... 

`
<record id="menu_solutions" model="website.menu">
        <field name="name">Solutions</field>
        <field name="sequence" type="int">20</field>
    </record>

    <record id="menu_submenu_erp" model="website.menu">
        <field name="name">ERP</field>
        <field name="url">/shop</field>
        <field name="website_id" ref="website.default_website"/>
        <field name="parent_id" ref="website_main_menu.menu_solutions"/>
        <field name="sequence" type="int">20</field>
    </record>
`

Comment: yeah i do understand what you are trying to make me understand, but i did the same what you have descried in the example still i am not getting the submenues

Comment: This is only valid on creation, try to uninstall your module and reinstall it again to force Odoo to recreate the menu

Comment: This is only valid on creation, try to uninstall your module and reinstall it again to force Odoo to recreate the menu

Comment: Tried installing by creating a new database still the same..... and when i uninstall and again install extra 2 menu are getting created automatically

Comment: Tested on latest Odoo 15 and it worked as expected. I wish you good luck

Comment: Actually i solved it, what i did is.... i just added the `parent_id` to be `Top Menu for Website 1` and the `website_id ` to be the default website which is in my case `website_1` .....  now `ERP` is showing as subchild of `Solutions`